# Improving my code of Margrabe Formula in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I want to see how can I improve my code to make it faster and cleaner. Below you can see the code of Margrabe's Formula for pricing Exchange Options.

I think the part where I check if the argument is None and if not take predetermined values, can be improved but i don't know how to do it. Is using scipy.stats.norm for calculating the pdf and cdf of the normal distribution faster than manually coding it myself?

```
    from __future__ import division
    from math import log, sqrt, pi
    from scipy.stats import norm

    s1 = 10
    s2 = 20
    sigma1 = 1.25
    sigma2 = 1.45
    t = 0.5
    rho = 0.85

    def sigma(sigma1, sigma2, rho):
        return sqrt(sigma1**2 + sigma2**2 - 2*rho*sigma1*sigma2)

    def d1(s1, s2, t, sigma1, sigma2, rho):
        return (log(s1/s2)+ 1/2 * sigma(sigma1, sigma2, rho)**2 * t)/(sigma(sigma1, sigma2, rho) * sqrt(t))

    def d2(s1, s2, t, sigma1, sigma2, rho):
        return d1(s1,s2,t, sigma1, sigma2, rho) - sigma(sigma1, sigma2, rho) * sqrt(t)

    def Margrabe(stock1=None, stock2=None, sig1=None, sig2=None, time=None, corr=None):

        if stock1 == None:
            stock1 = s1
        if stock2 == None:
            stock2 = s2
        if time == None:
            time = t
        if sig1 == None:
            sig1 = sigma1
        if sig2 == None:
            sig2 = sigma2
        if corr==None:
            corr = rho

        dd1 = d1(stock1, stock2, time, sig1, sig2, corr)
        dd2 = d2(stock1, stock2, time, sig1, sig2, corr)
        return stock1*norm.cdf(dd1) - stock2*norm.cdf(dd2)

    print "Margrabe = " + str(Margrabe())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you compare to `None`, you are better off using `if stock1 is None:` - an object can define equality, so potentially using `==` could return `True` even when `stock1` is not `None`. Using `is` checks *identity*, so it will only return `True` in the case it really is `None`.

As to simplifying your code, you can simply place the default values directly into the function definition:

```
def margrabe(stock1=s1, stock2=s2, sig1=t, sig2=sigma1, time=sigma2, corr=rho):
    dd1 = d1(stock1, stock2, time, sig1, sig2, corr)
    dd2 = d2(stock1, stock2, time, sig1, sig2, corr)
    return stock1*norm.cdf(dd1) - stock2*norm.cdf(dd2)
```

This makes your code significantly more readable, and much shorter.

It is also worth a note that `CapWords` is reserved for classes in Python - for functions, use `lowercase_with_underscores` - this is defined in [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (which is a great read for making your Python more readable), and helps code highlighters work better, and your code more readable.